# header to be show only in "/" and "/checkout" react reuter dom

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom-server

I want  to be visible only during '/checkout' and '/' instead of in the whole path.
it is being difficult to do in react reuter dom v6.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";

function App() {
  return (
    // BEM
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useLocation()` hook in `Header` component and check `pathname` for needed conditions for rendering.

Header.js

```
  import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
  ....
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

JSX

```
return (
  <div>
     {!pathname.includes("login") && <div>Not Login page</div>}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

On `react-router` v6 you can make Layout for specific routes. You can add `<Outlet/>` to detect all route child like code below. [Documentation React-Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

```
function App() {
  return (
    // BEM
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
               <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
               <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Code for Layout.jsx

```
import {Outlet} from "react-router"

const Layout = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <Outlet/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: that't not working mate, if possible contact me on linkedin to resolve my bug  https://www.linkedin.com/in/vishalmishra2810/

Comment: I use these method on my project that used react-router v6

Comment: If you have discrod feel free to add my account `WAD#5227`